# What is the config to attach transparent face to object

Tags: faces

I'm blender noob.

In the bottom picture, that selected face detached to the mesh.

Let me know the config to attach that transparent face to the mesh like the upper picture.
Thanks for helping me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please try to reformulate? Your face doesn't seem transparent, nor detached from the mesh.

Comment: I mean black square with dot detached to the mesh, It was squared on the mesh.. I add one more picture that I want

Comment: do you mean you want to attach the legs to the body?

Comment: Really thank you for your help, I might use wrong word "attach" or "detach" and no relation between pictures, those are just example./////// In bottom picture, there are many black square with dot. But these squares are not sticked(adjoin? idk what is right word;;) to the mesh like upper picture. Upper picture has curved square sticked to the mesh, there must be configuration to stick these squares to the mesh

Answer (score 0):

The little black square is always at the center of verts which creates the face. So if you have concave or non-flat ngons then the square won't be located on the surface, but this isn't a useful thing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about the edges that seemingly are not connected to your faces. See the selected edge in the images below.

[image: cage off]

[image: cage on]

This "floating clear face" problem will only show up in edit mode from objects with a [Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html). Reason being by default in edit mode you see the "cage mesh" (the vertices, edges, and faces without the modifier.) Blender also displays the modified mesh in edit mode. So in my top image you end up with the default cube (still visible as the cage) and a subdivided round ball in the center (the modified mesh.)

Notice the [Show on cage](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) button highlighted in red in the second image, that toggles the display of the cage to show on the modified mesh. (Shown in the second image.)

There is no problem with your mesh, no invisible faces, or unconnected parts, just a Subdivision Surface Modifier.